# Playing around Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

**Is there any mini C# console application available to pursue Reflection ?**

Comment: What do you mean, pursue? Reflection can be used in any type of application.

Comment: I mean i wish to acquire in depth knowledge of reflection in C#. I wish to develop an application like "Reflector".

Comment: @rengaseshan: No offence but reflector is already written, and it's expert territory to write something like it.

Comment: There is a quite good list of reflection samples here: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+reflection+tutorial

Comment: For Example I am pointing "Reflector". Actually i need to dynamically play around the assembly. so i wish imbibe deep programming knowledge in reflection. Clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

[SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)

Comment: Nice . Six months back i went through a link that is a game based on reflection ,very useful to learn how the technique works.but the link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) in Visual Studio?

I suggest that you try the types in the [System.Reflection namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) there. Play around with the Assembly, Field/MethodInfo, Activator and Type classes.
For learning about assemblies and IL look at the [System.Reflection.Emit namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx). A good example to start with is the one for the [TypeBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) for playing with `.NET` objects. Not `C#`, but really straightforward reflection on all `.NET` objects.

```
>>> import clr
>>> import System
>>> ip=System.Net.IPAddress(System.Array[System.Byte]([10,0,0,1]))
>>> ip
<System.Net.IPAddress object at 0x0000000000000034 [10.0.0.1]>
>>> dir(ip)
['Address', 'AddressFamily', 'Any', 'Broadcast', 'Equals', 'GetAddressBytes', 'G
etHashCode', 'GetType', 'HostToNetworkOrder', 'IPv6Any', 'IPv6Loopback', 'IPv6No
ne', 'IsIPv6LinkLocal', 'IsIPv6Multicast', 'IsIPv6SiteLocal', 'IsLoopback', 'Loo
pback', 'MemberwiseClone', 'NetworkToHostOrder', 'None', 'Parse', 'ReferenceEqua
ls', 'ScopeId', 'ToString', 'TryParse', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '
__eq__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__red
uce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__']
>>> ip.Address
16777226L
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the *Reflector* utility is a really nice utility to explorer .NET assemblies.

If you want to build your own reflection application to learn about how metadata is structured I would recommend you read [Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463). It gives a nice run down of how 
metadata is structured in assemblies today.

The .NET framework already exposes some reflection tools to developers, as stated by user "weiqure" and I would recommend that you sample the `System.Reflection` namespace to get started with reflection too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/fasterflect_.aspx which makes reflection "easier" to play with.